# LibGDX correct approach to Point Sprites for swarming?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, particles, particle-swarm

Bit of an open question, but I'll try and be as specific as possible.

I have written a few things in Android Studio, and now using Eclipse+LibGDX to look into gaming. It's a fairly high/med-level API to use so we can't see further down into the lower levels of how graphics are drawn. However, we know that it uses a quad-rendering method.

Now, this method works fine for most types of games, but if I wanted to look into swarming algorithms of particles (say, 1000 points), previously I used **Point Sprite** rendering. It appears libgdx doesn't use this method.

**Question**: Do you know if libgdx supports Point Sprites (1000+) independently moving around the screen (based on my own formulae). Quad rendering will slow down immensely with the number of sprites to be used. For example, 1000 balls bouncing around a box.

NOTE - I'm not looking at particle systems as they appear to be only Emitters and defining how the particles emit from that source (eg fireworks, explosions).

AIM: I plan to have many objects moving around the screen which, when viewed from afar, are rendered using a Point Sprite method (much faster for the sheer number of objects), and then revert to Quad Rendering when zoomed in (for details in the graphic). This is solely for optimisation purposes.

Is this something Libgdx would allow?

Many thanks for any help you can offer.

Kind regards,
J

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana While we welcome your effort to improve the quality of questions, just editing out a greeting is usually not considered a reason for an edit. Try to make edits as _substantial_ as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX fully exposes OpenGL ES functionality so if some of the more high-level library routines don't work for you then you are free to dig into GL_POINTS yourself. But I'd recommend you try without points first and see if you need to optimize it.

Comment: Ok, so try a performance test with 10 balls bouncing around, 100, 1000, 10000, etc until I get a noticeable lag? Is there a standard way, then, to show a different sprite if zoomed out, to help this performance? Again, just thinking about the level of detail when zoomed in is unencessary when zoomed out.

Comment: The only standard I can think of to automatically show different textures depending on sprite on screen pixel size would be mipmapping.  All you need to do is change your texture filter settings and at runtime smaller copies of your texture would be generated and used resulting in less texel work for OpenGL. See http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

Comment: Ok, I've got the two methods working. OLD method, in render() method, batch.begin, "for each ball, game.batch.draw(ballImage, ball.x, ball.y)", batch.end. -- NEW method: using stage and actors, in render() stage.act and stage.draw. However, the stage.draw is causing the FPS to drop hugely down to 8 or 9FPS, for just 1000 actor objects on the stage. No idea what's causing the huge drop

Comment: You were getting 60fps with SpriteBatch? Can you update question with your new code? Or start a new one if needed.

Comment: I've settled for a stage+camera for the UI elements (buttons, label, etc) with camera fixed to the device screen, and then the underlying balls drawn using sprite batch. Still getting 60fps with 10,000 sprites (small balls). Slight drop to about 55fps with 100,000 sprites, and complete drop to 9fps with 1,000,000 sprites. I won't be using numbers of sprites that big, so this method seems to work for me for now

Comment: Don't forget to increase the SpriteBatch size to reduce the number of flushes to the GPU. You didn't mention device type so I don't know how much memory is an issue but on mobile even simple objects can add up. If a ball is just a non-rotated, non-scaled, texture, try not having one object per ball. Make an array of floats (not Vector2) to hold all the x,y values.